# How do I programmatically set a RectTransform in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want my RectTransform to look like this:

[image]

I'm trying this:

```
m_Viewport = go.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
m_Viewport.anchorMin = Vector2.zero;
m_Viewport.anchorMax = Vector2.one;
m_Viewport.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
m_Viewport.localScale = Vector3.one;
m_Viewport.offsetMin = new Vector2(30, 0);
m_Viewport.offsetMax = new Vector2(0, 0);
m_Viewport.sizeDelta = new Vector2(-20, 0);
```

But it comes out like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
float left = 30;
float right = 20;

m_Viewport.anchorMin = Vector3.zero;
m_Viewport.anchorMax = Vector3.one;
m_Viewport.anchoredPosition = new Vector2((left - right)/2, 0f);
m_Viewport.sizeDelta = new Vector2(-(left + right), 0);
```

`sizeDelta` streches the rectTransform to left and right in the same proportion. As you want the left size different from the right size, you have to move the x position to adjust.

Comment: Please explain how this works. Nothing in there makes any sense at all, yet it makes it correctly. Say I wanted Left to be 60, what do I change?

Comment: TBH I had just put the inspector in Debug mode and copied the values. But I think I figured out a more readable code. I'm going to edit the answer.

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think is wrong way to set `sizeDelta`:

```
m_Viewport.sizeDelta = new Vector2(-(left + right), 0);
```

I changet it to:

```
m_Viewport.sizeDelta = new Vector2(parentSizeDelta.x - (left + right),                                         parentSizeDelta.y - (top + down));
```